# LSTM Time Series Anomaly detection

Tags: python, lstm, forecast, lstm-stateful

I am trying to find an anomaly in Time series with the LSTM. And I am still wondering, what should be the right architecture, timesteps, batch-size, sliding or non-sliding windows for finding an anomaly based on time series past behaviour

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, 
RepeatVector,TimeDistributed
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

X = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]) 
X_train = X.reshape(1, 8, 1)
y = X.reshape(1, 8)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(8, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, y, epochs=500, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
result = model.predict(X_train, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

It give me an output of

```
[0.11906812, 0.19180197, 0.30324116, 0.14811686, 25.3771758 ,
 0.52173275, 0.61532116, 0.7421335]
```

It is not looking like an anomaly sign to me. Is stateful a better way to find anomaly based on past behaviour? Even a normal Gaussian distribution can easily tell me the anomaly here, but it won't take the time effect

Comment: did you get any idea on this ?

Comment: Yes I solved it